# pagination and serial number php mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, pagination

Hello I have following code with serial NO. and pagination.
pagination is working but when I go to next page then serial number start from 1. I have limited 10 row in every page so I want to start next page from SN. 11-20 , 21-30 from 3rd page . please help me.

```html
<?php include_once("../database/config.php"); 

$start=0;
$limit=10;
$sn=$start;

if(isset($_GET['mainmdsid']))
{
 $mainmdsid=$_GET['mainmdsid'];
 $start=($mainmdsid-1)*$limit;
}
else{
 $mainmdsid=1;
}
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT *from item , mainmds , school WHERE empid=$empid AND mainmds.itmid=item.itmid AND mainmds.scid=school.scid LIMIT $start, $limit");     
  
    
?>
   <table align="center" id="customers">

 <tr>
  <th>SN.</th>
  <th>Item Name</th>
  <th>Quantity</th>
  <th>Status</th>
  <th>If unsatisfactory provide comments </th>
  <th>Date</th>
  <th>School Name</th>
  <th>Variant</th>
  <th>Thana</th>
  
  <th>If others then please specify </th>
  <th>Remove</th>   
  
 </tr>
 
 <?php 
 //while($res = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { // mysql_fetch_array is deprecated, we need to use mysqli_fetch_array 
 while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
 $sn+=1;
 
 $sdate = $res['sdate'];
 $fmdate = strtotime($sdate);
 
   
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>".$sn."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$res['itmname']."</td>";
  
   if (strpos($empbranch,"NFO")!==false) {
  echo "<td>".$res['DNFO']."</td>"; 
  }
  else if (strpos($empbranch,"DFO")!==false) {
  echo "<td>".$res['DDFO']."</td>"; 
  }
  else if (strpos($empbranch,"CO")!==false) {
  echo "<td>".$res['DCO']."</td>"; 
  }
  else if (strpos($empbranch,"SHARP")!==false) {
  echo "<td>".$res['DSHARP']."</td>"; 
  }
  else if (strpos($empbranch,"Other")!==false) {
  echo "<td>".$res['DOther']."</td>"; 
  }
  echo "<td>".$res['istatus']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$res['usstatus']."</td>";
  
  echo "<td>".$res['sdate']."</td>";
  echo "<td>" .date('d M Y', $fmdate). "</td>";
  echo "<td>".$res['ivariant']."</td>"; 
  echo "<td>".$res['scthana']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$res['oscname']."</td>";
  
   
  
   
  
  echo "<td><a href=\"delete.php?mainmdsid=$res[mainmdsid]\" onClick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')\">Delete</a></td></tr>";  
 }
 ?>
  </table>
  
  <?php
//fetch all the data from database.
$rows=mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($dbconfig,"SELECT *from item , mainmds , school WHERE empid=$empid AND mainmds.itmid=item.itmid AND mainmds.scid=school.scid"));
//calculate total page number for the given table in the database 
$total=ceil($rows/$limit);?>
<table align="center" border="1">
<?php if($mainmdsid>1)
{
 //Go to previous page to show previous 10 items. If its in page 1 then it is inactive
 echo "<tr><td><a href='?mainmdsid=".($mainmdsid-1)."' class='button'>PREVIOUS</a></td>";
}
if($mainmdsid!=$total)
{
 ////Go to previous page to show next 10 items.
 echo "<td><a href='?mainmdsid=".($mainmdsid+1)."' class='button'>NEXT</a></td>";
}
?>

<?php
//show all the page link with page number. When click on these numbers go to particular page. 
  for($i=1;$i<=$total;$i++)
  {
   if($i==$mainmdsid) { echo "<td>".$i."</td>"; }
   
   else { echo "<td><a href='?mainmdsid=".$i."'>".$i."</a></td>"; }
  }
?>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Note that limit without order by is fairly meaningless

Answer (score 1):

just move your `$sn` initialization after if condition

```
$start=0;
$limit=10;

if(isset($_GET['mainmdsid']))
{
    $mainmdsid=$_GET['mainmdsid'];
    $start=($mainmdsid-1)*$limit;
}
else{
    $mainmdsid=1;
}
$sn=$start;
```

Answer (score 0):

change your code to this... it will work

```
<?php include_once("../database/config.php"); 

    $start=0;
    $limit=10;

    if(isset($_GET['mainmdsid']))
    {
        $mainmdsid=$_GET['mainmdsid'];
        $start=($mainmdsid-1)*$limit; // here we are multiplying page number with limit.
    }

    $sn=$start;

    if(isset($_GET['mainmdsid']))
    {
        $mainmdsid=$_GET['mainmdsid'];
        $start=($mainmdsid-1)*$limit;
    }
    else{
        $mainmdsid=1;
    }
           $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT *from item , mainmds , school WHERE empid=$empid AND mainmds.itmid=item.itmid AND mainmds.scid=school.scid LIMIT $start, $limit");      


    ?>
                <table align="center" id="customers">

        <tr>
            <th>SN.</th>
            <th>Item Name</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>If unsatisfactory provide comments </th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>School Name</th>
            <th>Variant</th>
            <th>Thana</th>

            <th>If others then please specify </th>
            <th>Remove</th>         

        </tr>

        <?php 
        //while($res = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { // mysql_fetch_array is deprecated, we need to use mysqli_fetch_array 
        while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { 
        $sn+=1;

        $sdate = $res['sdate'];
        $fmdate = strtotime($sdate);


            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$sn."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$res['itmname']."</td>";

                if (strpos($empbranch,"NFO")!==false) {
            echo "<td>".$res['DNFO']."</td>";   
            }
            else if (strpos($empbranch,"DFO")!==false) {
            echo "<td>".$res['DDFO']."</td>";   
            }
            else if (strpos($empbranch,"CO")!==false) {
            echo "<td>".$res['DCO']."</td>";    
            }
            else if (strpos($empbranch,"SHARP")!==false) {
            echo "<td>".$res['DSHARP']."</td>"; 
            }
            else if (strpos($empbranch,"Other")!==false) {
            echo "<td>".$res['DOther']."</td>"; 
            }
            echo "<td>".$res['istatus']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$res['usstatus']."</td>";

            echo "<td>".$res['sdate']."</td>";
            echo "<td>" .date('d M Y', $fmdate). "</td>";
            echo "<td>".$res['ivariant']."</td>";   
            echo "<td>".$res['scthana']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$res['oscname']."</td>";





            echo "<td><a href=\"delete.php?mainmdsid=$res[mainmdsid]\" onClick=\"return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')\">Delete</a></td></tr>";        
        }
        ?>
         </table>

         <?php
    //fetch all the data from database.
    $rows=mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($dbconfig,"SELECT *from item , mainmds , school WHERE empid=$empid AND mainmds.itmid=item.itmid AND mainmds.scid=school.scid"));
    //calculate total page number for the given table in the database 
    $total=ceil($rows/$limit);?>
    <table align="center" border="1">
    <?php if($mainmdsid>1)
    {
        //Go to previous page to show previous 10 items. If its in page 1 then it is inactive
        echo "<tr><td><a href='?mainmdsid=".($mainmdsid-1)."' class='button'>PREVIOUS</a></td>";
    }
    if($mainmdsid!=$total)
    {
        ////Go to previous page to show next 10 items.
        echo "<td><a href='?mainmdsid=".($mainmdsid+1)."' class='button'>NEXT</a></td>";
    }
    ?>

    <?php
    //show all the page link with page number. When click on these numbers go to particular page. 
            for($i=1;$i<=$total;$i++)
            {
                if($i==$mainmdsid) { echo "<td>".$i."</td>"; }

                else { echo "<td><a href='?mainmdsid=".$i."'>".$i."</a></td>"; }
            }
    ?>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Thanks, really very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

On click off every next page button, increase the limit of `$start` from 0 to +10.
and again call your DB Query, and for previous button decrement value of `$start` to -10.
And also use variable `currentPage` and sets it value to 1 in start.

Here is sample code which you can use :

```
$currentPage = 1;
$start = 0;
$recordPerPage= 10;

//First query your database here, after that do some work on previous and next button clicked

if(array_key_exists('next',$_POST)){
   $start = (currentPage * recordPerPage) + 1;
   currentPage++;
}
if(array_key_exists('previous',$_POST)){
   if (currentPage == 2) {
        offSet = 0;
        currentPage--;
    } else {
        offSet = offSet - recordPerPage;
        currentPage--;
    }
}
```

This way you can handle current page, limit and offset. Remember to call DB Query on next and previous button clicked

Comment: Thanks you very much

Comment: marked answer right, if you have solved your problem